# Why is RedirectToAction not redirecting?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In a Action, I am calling

```
RedirectToAction("login", new { test = "1" });
```

And the page doesn't seem to be redirecting.  The action "login" is in the same controller.

What could the issue be?

Comment: Your returning RedirectToAction(...) right, not "calling" it?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should use

```
return RedirectToAction(...
```

Answer (score 3):

RedirectToAction(... will not work if you are using AJAX form. ajax request simply ignore the redirect call

Comment: agree with you, you would need to do the redirection on the client side on success of ajax post (for example); by using jquery or javascript. @jawahar

Answer (score 1):

You have to use return the RedirectToAction.